# Using Neural Net to determine variables to use in curve fitting equation

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, curve-fitting

I have a data set that comprises rate vs. time data for flow performance.  It is typically structured as:

```
time = [1,2,4,5,6,7, 8, 9 10]
rate = [100, 62, 40, 31, 25, 21, 18, 16, 14, 13]
```

This data is described by a hyperbolic decline model of the form:

```
Q = Qi*(1+Di*b*Ti)^-(1/b)
```

with the constraints:

```
0 <b <= 2
Di > 0
Qi > 0
Ti = time(i)
```

Although the data is quite noisy, in many cases it is very, very well described by the equation above, and using something like a least-squares curve fitting method you often get an answer that a human interpreter would validate.

However, there are cases when the mathematically best solution is not the desirable solution (there is an emphasis by human interpreters on ignoring noise and matching late time data), so a human interpreter would need to override the results.  Obviously the solution is non-unique, so there are many acceptable answers

I have gone through a data set of nearly 4000 rate-time pairs and manually evaluated the least-squares generated solution, and corrected it if necessary.

My question: I would like to train a model to "guess" the best solution for Qi, Di, and b in the equation above, with the my manually evaluated data set serving as the training data.  Is this a valid use case for implementing a neural network?

Comment: You might consider using scipy's optimize.differential_evolution module to estimate initial parameters for fitting. I have an example of using this scipy module for fitting a double Lorentzian peak equation to Raman spectroscopy of carbon nanotubes at https://bitbucket.org/zunzuncode/RamanSpectroscopyFit - the module uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space and so requires parameter bounds within which to search, however these bounds can be quite generous.

Comment: I have a very similar problem. Scipy's curve_fit sometimes gives unreasonable fits.